# .asp addling links with images

Tags: image, asp-classic, xhtml, dreamweaver

I am using dreamweaver cs6 and working with a .asp file (xhtml)

I have my links all set proper from what I can tell but for some reason when I add the  code it gives me a nasty boarder around my image I am using for a link.

The code I have prior to adding the link is in list form.

```
<div class="sidebar1">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><img src="../images/homebutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><img src="../images/blogbutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><img src="../images/eventsbutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><img src="../images/contactbutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
   <li><img src="../images/affiliates.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><img src="../images/forums.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
</ul>
<!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
```

That works just fine. My images are in place and look nice.

The problem arises when I add the link code

```
<div class="sidebar1">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/welcome.html"><img src="../images/homebutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/blogbutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><a href="/events.html"><img src="../images/eventsbutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><a href="/contactus.html"><img src="../images/contactbutton.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
   <li><a href="/affiliates.html"><img src="../images/affiliates.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/forums.png" width="160" height="54" /></li>
</ul>
<!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
```

Adding the  into the code seems to make a border around my images. I cannot seem to find out why. Could be something I am just overseeing. I have no borders set for the CSS side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To remove border, add this to your CSS Code

```
.nav li a { outline: none; }
```

Comment: No luck, although another thing I did notice is it seems to see the space between the
    <a href="#">THIS RIGHT HERE<img src="#">

as a space although there is none in the code.

http://50.63.78.103/nev/Templates/Untitled-1.asp thats the link to show you what its doing.

Comment: The code you have posted has no closing </a> tags... Check your code

Comment: I added the closing, that was stupid on my part sorry, still getting the boarders though.

Comment: adding the li a { outline: none; } in the css after closing the links did help a bit, now i have bullet points but the borders are gone.

Comment: To remove the bullets part, add this to your css code `.nav li { list-style: none; }`

Comment: Thank you so much. Simple mistakes on my end. You are awesome.